# Average Annual Temperature

Tags: web-services

Hello guys,
          Is there any webservice which gives average annual temperature when provided date.

Thanks,
sush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Weather Underground](http://www.wunderground.com). Enter a location, then click "Today's Almanac." Under that tab, there's another link that says "View more history data." From there, you can see lots of information about any particular date.